# TestContainer what is the difference between withStartupTimeout and waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort())?

Tags: java, testcontainers

TestContainers [doc](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/startup_and_waits/) states

> Ordinarily Testcontainers will wait for up to 60 seconds for the
> container's first mapped network port to start listening.
>
> This simple measure provides a basic check whether a container is
> ready for use.

If I am starting my container like below

```
var sharedKafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse(DOCKER_KAFKA_IMAGE_NAME));
sharedKafkaContainer.withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(3, ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
```

Then the container will wait for 3 mins for the exposed or mapped port to start listening.

The below code is a succinct representation of the above and there is no difference between `withStartupTimeout` and `waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort())` Is my understanding correct?

```
var sharedKafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse(DOCKER_KAFKA_IMAGE_NAME));
sharedKafkaContainer.withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(3, ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
sharedKafkaContainer.waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort()).start()
```

Comment: The `sharedKafkaContainer.waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort())` actually does not change anything as it actually resets the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're same. The `waitingFor` method allows you to pass your custom implementation of the `WaitStrategy` interface which can check for any arbitrary condition to see if given container is up or not. The `Wait.forListeningPort` returns an instance of `HostPortWaitStrategy` which is one implementation of the `WaitStrategy`, checking for a specific port to be available and consider that as a criteria to mark a container as ready.